# Can I add too much opti-red?

Tags: wine, additives, red-wine

I have some extra opti-red from last year that I'd like to use up.  Is there a danger if I add too much of it?  Should I just toss it?

What are the cons of opti-red?  Can it make the wine taste more artificial or flabby?

https://www.morebeer.com/products/optired.html

Comment: Is there any Best Before date on the package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opti-red, is a yeast derived mix of polysacchrides, which are designed to bind to polyphenols/tannis and provide fuller body and better colour stability.

I would not add more than the recommended dose, not becuase it will do you harm, but due to the fact the manufacturer has calculated and adding any more is a waste and may advresely affect the finished wine.

If it is about to go out of date, I would use what is recommended then dispose of the rest.

Regarding best before dates their data sheet states: "Opti-Red should be stored in a cool, dry place. Un-opened, Opti-Red has a shelf-life of 3 years."